# IOS textFieldDidChange when outlet in other class

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I've got a specific iOS question when accessing an outlet on a different class.

In my project I have a UItableView with custom tableViewCells which I have created using the interface builder. These cells have UItextfields on them and I need to know when a value of a certain textfield is changed. (so I can add a new empty cell with textfield, just like in your address book) I came across the following function

```
[UITextfield addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

The problem is that I use this function in the main class when the outlet of the textfield is in the subclass (specific tableViewCell class).

I Created an Method of the outlet so I could access it in the main class. But still is above code does not trigger the textFieldDidChange event.

Hope someone could help me with this problem. Or give me a different solution to achieve my goal (creating an new empty textfield when adding the first character to the current UITextfield).

Thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

textFieldDidChange doesn't work. Well, I had a lot of problems with it.
I don't know if it's deprecated or something.
Either way you can use shouldChangeCharacterInRange almost same way as long as it's delegated correctly.

But you have to modify it a bit because the method is triggered before you actually typed something. So you have to get the new value and add it yourself.

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)aTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
// Check the replacementString
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch, it worked! still got another problem. When reloading the UiTableview or use the reloadSections function the keyboard hides. But I need it to stay visible. Can't figure out how to fix this problem..

Comment: If my answer now works I think you should make my answer correct or at least upvote =) try [yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
If the responder is set your keyboard should stay up. To bring it down you can use [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];

Comment: Hey Frederik, I'm sorry, brand new at Stackoverflow so didn't know that... but I checked it =) (sorry can't voteup because of my reputation). The becomeFirstResponder thing also worked =D. I really appreciate you're help, you have put me back on track!